# Rscript -e breaking on spaces when sshing from OSX, but not from linux

Tags: r, bash, rscript

I've got an interesting issue where `Rscript` is breaking on the first space it finds:

```sh
$ Rscript --vanilla -e "1 + 1"
[1] 1
```

Similarly:

```sh
$ Rscript --vanilla -e "print('one'); print('two')"
[1] "one"
$ Rscript --vanilla -e "print('one');print('two')"
[1] "one"
[1] "two"
```

These commands are being executed on a linux machine. Strangely, the problem **only** occurs when I'm logging into the linux machine from a laptop running OSX. If I log onto the linux machine from a laptop running linux, `Rscript` behaves itself and doesn't break on the space.

Is this the expected behaviour for `Rscript`? Does anybody know how to ensure `Rscript` executes all expressions after `-e`?

Thanks! I'm using (on the remote linux box):

```
$ Rscript --version
R scripting front-end version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
$ $SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce output of either statement in PowerShell on Win10. Will check later on a Linux machine.

Comment: No, this is not normal. What’s `Rscript` (`which Rscript; type $(which Rscript)`)?

Comment: It seems to be breaking on spaces. I'm guessing it's a weird $SHELL or $TERM problem.

Comment: In this breaking case, `Rscript` is running on a remote linux box. Strangely, if we log into the machine from a *linux* laptop, `Rscript` behaves nicely. If we log into the remote box from *OSX*, `Rscript` breaks in the way shown above.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - 
`/cvmfs/soft.mugqic/CentOS6/software/R_Bioconductor/R_Bioconductor-3.5.0_3.7/bin/Rscript`

and 
`/cvmfs/soft.mugqic/CentOS6/software/R_Bioconductor/R_Bioconductor-3.5.0_3.7/bin/Rscript is /cvmfs/soft.mugqic/CentOS6/software/R_Bioconductor/R_Bioconductor-3.5.0_3.7/bin/Rscript` (loaded from modules)